# wifiManager addNetwork() succeeds but network not visible under Wi-Fi Settings

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

I have successfully added and connected to open and PSK networks programmatically in my app (tried on devices running 5.1 as well as 6.0). However when I am trying this for enterprise network it does not work. I see that addNetwork() succeeds (returns positive net id) but when I look under Settings->Wi-Fi I don't see the SSID like I do for the other SSIDs I added. Anyone know why this would be? If I search the WiFiConfiguration list programmatically it does find the SSID. Here is the code I use:

```
wifiConf = new WifiConfiguration();
wifiConf.SSID = "\"dot1x-test\"";
wifiConf.BSSID = "c4:e9:84:43:48:e8";
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
    wifiConf.enterpriseConfig.setIdentity("name");
    wifiConf.enterpriseConfig.setPassword("testpassword");
    wifiConf.enterpriseConfig.setEapMethod(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP);
    wifiConf.enterpriseConfig.setPhase2Method(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Phase2.MSCHAPV2);
}

netId = wifiMgr.addNetwork(wifiConf);
wifiMgr.disconnect();
wifiMgr.enableNetwork(netId, true);
wifiMgr.saveConfiguration();
wifiMgr.reconnect();
```